# Paypal PHP API - UNAUTHORIZED_AGREEMENT_REQUEST

Tags: php, paypal

I am setting up a Payment agreement using Paypal Rest API.

In sandbox mode, this works fine, I can create the Plan and set up the agreement for the plan.

however when going live, I get the following error:

```
UNAUTHORIZED_AGREEMENT_REQUEST
You don't have permission to create such agreement.
```

I have Enhanced Recurring Payments enabled on my account. So , I thought that would be all that was required.

The steps I am taking are:

```
 $plan = new Plan();
 ....
$output = $plan->create($apiContext);
$planID = $output->getId();
```

Then create the agreement based on the PlanId

```
$agreement = new Agreement();
....
 $plan->setId($planID);
 $agreement->setPlan($plan);
 .....
 $createagreement = $agreement->create($apiContext);
```

The $agreement->create is the call that is failing.

Is there something I am meant to enable either on the site or on the developer app settings in order to get this to work, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you provide the debug id received in the PayPal response ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia While it worked in sand box mode, It doesnt work in all regions on the live site. Pay Pal told me this, while it wasn't clearly stated that this was the case, it was the issue for me. You may want to check with Pay Pal to find out if its available in your region.

Comment: @CharlieSmith I asked you this to if my answer helped you to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Ask the paypal MTS executive via mail they will help you within Hours here is the link
[Paypal MTS](https://ppmts.custhelp.com)

Believe me they are very helpful